# What packages should I install in order to run Unity game?

Tags: unity, games

As a contribution to the 34th Ludum Dare I developed a game on Windows 10 by using Unity 5 framework. I exported it for both 32b and 64b versions of Windows and a 64b version of OSX. All of them work perfectly fine.

I also wanted to export it for the linux users as I exported it as both 32b a 64b binaries for Linux. However, on my Ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't work. To be specific, I mark the file as executable and run it (from concole). It flashes and crashes without any error.

I suppose there must be some set o packages I must have installed such as mono. Could you please suggest what to install in order to run such games?

EDIT1:

```
$ ldd game
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdd6f0b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f333660b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f33363ed000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f33361e5000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f3335f7f000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x0000003bf5a00000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x0000003bfb200000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x0000003bfba00000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3335c03000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f33358fd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f33356e6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3335321000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f333680f000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f33350fa000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f3334ee8000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x0000003bf8e00000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f3334ce2000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x0000003c08200000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x0000003c0be00000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x0000003c0b200000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x0000003c04600000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x0000003c0ca00000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x0000003c0ba00000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x0000003bf5600000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x0000003c03e00000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x0000003c03600000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f3334ad6000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f33348cc000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x0000003bf5200000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x0000003bf4e00000)
```

Comment: As a workaround there is http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html unity plugin that plays unity games using wine in native linux browsers which supporst npapi such as firefox .

Comment: @kenn yeah, I know about that, but it's not this case. I have a linux binary which I'd like to run directly... And according to Unity this should be possible... Thanks for another option, though :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is an executable which can be executed as a Linux executable, but is missing the correct linkage to be run on any of them.

That information you have given is exactly what you need to start to solve the situation. You need to go to Ubuntu package search then Search the contents of packages. https://packages.ubuntu.com/

You may then need to link files where filenames differ in order to get your executable to work. You may also need to download and compile some third-party stuff not in the Ubuntu repositories.

Unfortunately this is a common problem with running executable not compiled using the target distribution. Who know what MacGyvering of shared objects were done inside of unity to make an executable. It's most likely different for osx since it is a singular platform with one structure, while Linux is multiple distributions with many different structures. Rather what you have there is an executable which can be executed as a Linux executable, but is missing the correct linkage to be run on any of them.

Without sharing your file, you are the person who has to research how to get that particular file to run - and get it to run on different versions of Ubuntu.

I would like to note - I've had the exact opposite experience to you. Some years back I wrote something on Unity, and while I was expecting problems when I ran it on Ubuntu, it ran without any problems. The issues you're having are more than likely related to a component of your game. Maybe some 3rd party stuff?

Sorry for not being so very helpful, and responding to an old thread. But I thought I should even if it is. An answer is better than none.